# Загрузить данные в dataGridView из текстового файла (C#)

Tags: c#, datagridview

Имеется текстовый файл:

> Михаил Ролин 1978 Адвокат
>   Максим Левонов 1979 Бухгалтер
>   И т.д

Как загрузить данные в `DataGridView`?
(Названия столбцов настроены вручную в WindowsForm)

Пробовал данный код, но он работает не так, как мне нужно:

```
string[] array;
using (System.IO.StreamReader read = new System.IO.StreamReader("File.txt"))
{
    array = read.ReadToEnd().Split(new Char[] { ' ', '\r' });
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) //Где 4 - кол-во столбцов
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (array[pos] != "")
                dataGridView1[j, i].Value = array[pos];
            pos++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Прикрепите ваш код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементарно же:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("File.txt"))
{
    var array = line.Split();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(array);
}
```

Это работает при условии, что количество колонок в `DataGridView` строго совпадает с количеством разделённых пробелами слов в каждой строке файла.

Comment: А как можно сохранить текст из таблицы в текстовый файл?

Comment: @Varagian - задавайте _новый_ вопрос. Обязательно приложите собственный код с попыткой решения.